# Changes in win32api v2to3? Can import it fine in Python v3 but throws an error in v2

Tags: python, winapi, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been working with Python over the last few months, writing a few apps in version 3.3  I now need to write an app that references modules only in v2, so I'm starting to work with Python 2.7.5  I wrote a similar app in v3, so I thought I'd start there by modifying some of the code I uses in 3.3 to 2.7.5

However, I am at the VERY beginning and am already stumped.  I downloaded python 2.7 as well as pywin32 for 2.7.  However, I am getting an import error involving the win32api module, which is needed for win32com.client.

Here's the code I used in 3.3, which works

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from adodbapi import *
from time import sleep
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib
import string
import csv

from urllib.request import urlopen
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.parse import quote
```

Here's the code from 2.7, which does not work

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import adodbapi 
from time import sleep
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib, urllib2
import string
import csv

from urllib2 import urlopen 
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib import quote
```

The specific error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...", line 1, in <module>
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

when I run

```
help ('modules')
```

in 2.7.5, I see that win32api does exist and is found by PYTHONPATH.  I can import sys & os without issue.  The issue definitely lies with win32api.  This seems so basic.  What am I missing??